# SQL - Select from TableA, then Select Count from TableA

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count

I have TableA. It has a list of ID data by date.

ID's can have multiple records.

```
ID STARTDATE
-- ------------
1  APR-1-2017
2  JAN-1-2017
3  JULY-5-2016
4  DEC-6-2015
5  FEB-3-2017
5  JAN-1-2018
1  JAN-1-2018
```

I want to be able to select any particular date or date range, which will give me ID's for that date. Then I want to select the count for those ID's for past 365 days.

I was able to get the query working. But the only problem is the application I am using doesn't understand `WITH` Temp Table.

Is there an alternate way to write this query?

```
WITH list_to_compare as (select distinct(ID) AS LASTWEEKOUT 
                        from TABLEA 
                        WHERE TIMESTAMP >= SYSDATE -1)
SELECT TABLEA.ID,count(*)
    from list_to_compare LTC 
        LEFT OUTER join TABLEA 
            on LTC.lastweekout = TABLEA.ID
WHERE TABLEA.TIMESTAMP >= SYSDATE - 365 
group by TABLEA.ID
having COUNT(*) > 12;
```

Comment: On a sidenote: You should not call a column `ID` when it's not the table's ID. From a column called `ID` we expect this to uniquely identify a record in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to select data for certain IDs. For some reason you think you must join those IDs to your table, but actually it's just criteria and better belongs in the `WHERE` clause. (You even pseudo outer join the table to the IDs, although you know from the dates that you will always have a match.)

Here is the query with the criteria placed in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select id, count(*)
from tablea
where id in (select id from tablea where timestamp >= sysdate - 1)
and timestamp >= sysdate - 365 
group by id
having count(*) > 12;
```

But as you are aggregating anyway, you can even look up all criteria in the `HAVING` clause, thus selecting from the table just once:

```
select id, count(*)
from tablea
where timestamp >= sysdate - 365 
group by id
having count(*) > 12
and count(case when timestamp >= sysdate - 1 then 1 end) > 0;
```

Comment: Ty so much, I had actually ran into an issue and your suggestion fixed that issue too.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand exactly what you need, however you can just replace the `WITH` table with an inner select

```
SELECT Table1.ID,count(*)
    from (select distinct(ID) AS LASTWEEKOUT from Table1) LTC LEFT OUTER join Table1  on LTC.lastweekout = Table1.ID
WHERE Table1.STARTDATE >= SYSDATE - 365 
group by Table1.ID
having COUNT(*) > 12;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply move the WITH factoring clause's "table" into an inline view:

```
SELECT TABLEA.ID,count(*)
    from (select distinct(ID) AS LASTWEEKOUT 
          from TABLEA 
          WHERE TIMESTAMP >= SYSDATE -1) LTC
    LEFT OUTER join TABLEA  on LTC.lastweekout = TABLEA.ID
WHERE TABLEA.TIMESTAMP >= SYSDATE - 365 
group by TABLEA.ID
having COUNT(*) > 12;
```

Answer (score 1):

> …the application I am using doesn't understand WITH Temp Table.

There's a good chance it just doesn't like the *outer* query to start with `WITH` — you can solve this generically by wrapping every query with `select * from (…)`:

> ```
> with w as (select * from dual)
> select * from w;
> ```
>
> ```
> | DUMMY |
> | :---- |
> | X     |
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from ( with w as (select * from dual)
>        select * from w );
> ```
>
> ```
> | DUMMY |
> | :---- |
> | X     |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=20a1106e8ec3f5a517d306cb53766d03)*